# Battery percentage on iPod touch 5G iOS 8

Tags: ios, ipod

How do I get the battery percentage on the top right of my screen please help I tried many other things but didn't work

Answer (score 3):

The iPod Touch does not allow you to view battery percentage. Only the iPhone and iPad.

**"You can see what percent the battery is at on your iPhone or iPad, but not your iPod touch."** -- http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201102

Answer (score 2):

To enable it you will need to use a 3rd party application (no jailbreak required!).

Steps:

- Backup your device to iTunes (don't think encrypted backup will work)
- Download [iBackupBot](http://www.icopybot.com/download.htm)
- Open iBackupBot
- Select your most recent backup
- Double click on the file called `Library/Preferences/com.apple.springboard.plist`
- Add this under the first `<dict>`

> ```
> <key>SBShowBatteryLevel</key>
>     <true/>
> <key>SBShowBatteryPercentage</key>
>     <true/>
> ```

- Save the file
- Restore via `iBackupBot`

To undo it just take the code out.
Note: the code may be later on in the file due to how plist files are saved.

I would recommend making 2 backups just incase you mess up the edit (you shouldn't mess it up though)